# Override SuperTable reverse related entries limit

Tags: templating, plugin-supertable

I've got two kinds of channel entries: `Bills` and `Legislators`. `Legislators` have a SuperTable of votes. Each vote is related to one `Bill`. I want to get all the votes associated with a particular `Bill` and display them on that `Bill`'s page, but I can't fetch more than 100 items. Here's my current code:

```
{% set reverseRelatedVotes = craft.supertable.getRelatedElements({
    relatedTo: {
        targetElement: entry,
        field: 'scorecardVotes.bill',
        },
    section: 'legislators'
}).limit(null).order('lastName ASC') %}
```

`limit(10)` works as expected, but anything over the standard Craft limit of 100 returns 100. How can I get all the related votes for a given `Bill`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I needed to remove the limit earlier in the process: adding 'limit' => null after line 72 of SuperTableVariable.php did the trick.

I'll submit a pull request to that effect as soon as I figure out how to do that.